# Responsive Layout in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, responsive-design

I am making an android application and want to make it responsive but how can I do I can't understand.
I have tried :

1. use match_parent and wrap_content but not make responsive for all screen sizes.
2. I have added code in the Manifest file

```
Resources/layout-large/my_layout.xml // layout for large screen size    
Resources/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml // layout for extra-large screen size
Resources/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

3. I am using Genric Layout Nexus 5 in layout size.

Comment: Read this : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes & https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support

Answer (score 1):

in Xamarin.android to make reponsive layout must create many folders contain on layouts:
[Example on folders:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPCdN.png)

layout-sw360dp-h550dp : this for devices in size from 5 to 6.5 inch
sw : meaning screen width
h: meaning screen height
to know size of screens review this site:
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/ideal-screen-sizes-for-responsive-design

Comment: note: each folder contain same layouts , you must edit sizes in all layouts